# Passing a command line argument (as a string) into my Perl script

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm extremely new at Perl and trying to prove I can pick it up quickly. What I was asked to do is add a string as an argument on my command line, and then feed that into my script. From there it is supposed to search a MySQL table I've made for matches in one column, and spit the contents of another column into an array. It was suggested I used the Getops:Std but I'm uncertain how exactly to do that, and if that's the best technique.

For example: I have a MySQL table with car manufacturers, and car models. I want to run, Perl myscript.pl Ford, and then have it shoot me back an array with

Mustang
Escape
Focus

But I'm uncertain how to get that string input in the first place. Would Getops:Std be best? If so how would it be written? I'm picking this up quickly, but I've been at it less than a week, so the simpler the explanation, the better.

Edit: Basically I was confused why it was suggested I should use GetOpts::Std for this. It seems to be completely inappropriate for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Before you post here, **please search**. Type your question's title in Google at the very least. Look at the proposed suggestion in the "ask question" interface. Now look at the "Related" side-bar on this very page.

Comment: Also, I don't need the entire script explained, mostly just how to pass a string argument into my file and then use it to search my table.

Comment: This is pretty fundamental Perl you're asking about here. I really don't want to help you try *"to prove I can pick it up quickly"* since after a week you should know this so you clearly can't.

Comment: That's two completely different questions. But you'll find answers to both with a trivial amount of web searching. If you have a _specific_ problem with either, post the code you have so far and explain what's not working/the precise thing you're not getting to work.

Comment: Look, I'm completely new at coding/scripting, but I need to pick it up for work. Basically I'm wondering why it was suggested I use GetOps::Std at all if I'm just passing strings. I've been searching but none of the literature I've found has been particularly helpful or given me an exact script with an input and output which I can digest.

Comment: Spend a little time and curl up with a good book. Learning programming takes a little time. I suggest [The Modern Perl Book](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html) and its free!

Answer (score 1):

GetOpts::Std is overkill for this. Your command line arguments are in `@ARGV`. If you haven't been able to work that out after a week, then you need [better](http://learn.perl.org/) [references](http://perl-tutorial.org/) for Perl.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument will be in $ARGV[0], the second in $ARGV[1] , and so on.
You should check the [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.625/DBI.pm) module. Google for some tutorial out there.

Then try to write your script and post more specific questions with some code if you need more help.